# How does the private keyword let us both declare and initialize a class instance?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I'm reading [the Nest.js documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#:%7E:text=The%20CatsService%20is%20injected%20through%20the%20class%20constructor.%20Notice%20the%20use%20of%20the%20private%20syntax.%20This%20shorthand%20allows%20us%20to%20both%20declare%20and%20initialize%20the%20catsService%20member%20immediately%20in%20the%20same%20location), and there is a line that I don't quite understand.

We customize our CatsController using its constructor function, so when the IoC container creates the catsController instance, it is created with a catsService instance as a constructor parameter. At least this is my best guess based on the whole document. But what does the following exactly mean:

> Notice the use of the `private` syntax. This shorthand allows us to
> both declare and initialize the `catsService` member immediately in
> the same location.

Why does the private keyword achieve that? How would it look if we did not use the shorthand syntax?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties (if you click "Try" on the example you can see in the playground what it gets transpiled to).

Comment: I might misunderstand something. In my understanding, the TS documentation says that if I define class using this syntax, I can use this short hand to not type out the properties somewhat reduntantly. Then I can use the new keyword to instantiate the class just like I would.

But here in the Nest.js documentation (in my limited understanding) we are not defining the CatsService class, we are simply referencing it. Does the shorthand in the CatsController constructor mean that we create a catsService (omitting the new keyword) and it will be a class property of CatsController?

Comment: @szeb Then you are understanding something wrong. *Somewhere* the constructor for the `CatsController` class has to be called, otherwise there would be no way of using it. Maybe you don't do that explicitly and it's done by the Nest framework in the background, but it's called nonetheless. And at this call, a reference to the `CatService` is passed to that constructor ...

Comment: How exactly that instance of `CatsService` is created, and passed to the constructor of the `CatsController` when _that_ gets instantiated, is not part of TypeScript but part of what _Nest_ is doing. TypeScript's parameter properties shorthand just saves you from defining the property and the parameter separately then assigning the latter to the former inside the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialization of the CatsService is done by Nest.js in both cases, that's one of the key premises of the IoC it relies on. The usage of the `private` keyword in constructor declaration is completely optional, and is useful for making the constructor parameter an attribute of CatsController during its initialization. Without it, you should write:

```js
@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {
  private catsService: CatsService;
  
  constructor(service: CatsService) {
    this.catsService = service;
  }
  /* TODO */
}
```

Look at how the `private` keyword comes in place to declare the catsService as a private attribute of the class, and if we were to use it inside the constructor parameter declaration it would have the same meaning, resulting in a smaller and simpler code.
Lastly, this is a syntactic feature of Typescript, and has no relation with NestJS or DI.